# Must uwp ApplicationContentUriRules match completely?

Tags: webview, uwp

I would like to use **window.external.notify** from a webview loading content from the web in a uwp application.

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#interacting-with-webview-content)

> To enable an external web page to fire the ScriptNotify event when calling window.external.notify, you must include the page's Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) in the ApplicationContentUriRules section of the app manifest. (You can do this in Microsoft Visual Studio on the Content URIs tab of the Package.appxmanifest designer.) The URIs in this list must use HTTPS, and may contain subdomain wildcards (for example, https://.microsoft.com) but they cannot contain domain wildcards (for example, https://.com and https://.). The manifest requirement does not apply to content that originates from the app package, uses an ms-local-stream:// URI, or is loaded using NavigateToString.

My question is the following. If I declare the following uri in the manifest

- https://www.foo.bar

Does this map to only https://foo.bar or to other uris originating from it like

- https://www.foo.bar/foobar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By testing on my side, when adding the domain root Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) to  `ApplicationContentUriRules`, other pages under this folder in the server side could also work well, include the pages on subfolder.

So that to answer your question, `ApplicationContentUriRules` should be not only work for `https://foo.bar`, but also other `uris` originating from it.
[image][image]

If you need also to access pages from sub domains, you need to add `subdomain` wildcards as the document mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for testing this. After my own testing I reached the same conclusion.